# Biber gives "I found no \citation commands". Is there a solution ?

Tags: biblatex, biber

Help me, please, to fix the work of `biber`. When I put in `biblatex` options `backend=biber` then during the compilation I get:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2010)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

I just updated my TexLive 2010 at 23.05.2011 by the command `tlmgr update --all`
Maybe I do something wrong? Please, help.

**After correction: code added**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}

\usepackage[babel=false]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{german,english,greek,polish,russian}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid,citepages=suppress,sorting=nty]{biblatex}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{fortest.bib}

@Book{Kaluzh,
title = {Nowy sobór. Natura, historia przygotowań, tematyka},
author = {Tadeusz Kałużny},
publisher = {wydawnictwo księży Sercanów},
year = {2008},
location = {Krakóv},
}


@Book{AlKarapan,
author = {Αλέξανδρος Κ. Καραπαναγοπούλου},
title = {Η Μεγάλη Σ. της ΟΑΕ},
publisher = {Auto-édition},
year = {1990/1998},
volumes = {6},
location = {Αθήνα},
shorthand = {MS-OAE},
}


@Misc{Konst1923,
title = {Πρακτικὰ καὶ ἀποφάσεις τοῦ ἐν ΚΠΣ (10 μαΐου--8 ἰουνίου 1923)},
year = {1923},
location = {Κωνσταντινούπολη},
keywords = {primary}
}

@Article{Akury,
author = {Adolf Küry},
title = {Die Konferenz in Konstantinople},
journal = {Internationale kirchliche Zeitschrift},
year = {1924},
number = {14},
pages = {62--64}
}

@Online{Tichon1923enciclic,
title = {\textrussian{Послание Патриарха Тихона к православному народу о реформе календаря в РПЦ}},
date = {1923-10-01},
urldate = {2010-10-05},
url = {http://holyrussia.narod.ru/Tykhon_Calendar.html}
}

@Article{Echo1932,
journal = {Échos d'Orient},
title = {Le préconcile orthodoxe},
author = {J. Lacombe},
number = {31},
year = {1932},
pages = {239-241}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{conference.bib}


\begin{document}
test\footcite[331]{Kaluzh} est\footcite[23--27]{AlKarapan} test\footcite[23--27]{Konst1923} test\footcite[23--27]{Tichon1923enciclic} test\footcite[23--27]{Echo1932} test test

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of the tex file that caused these errors? Did you try deleting all the auxiliary files and recompiling?

Comment: check [here](http://www.mechpedia.gr/wiki/Biblatex) for a mwe involving greek and english references.

Comment: You are telling `biblatex` to use Biber, but your log is from BibTeX.

Comment: @Seamus I've tried to delete all aux files, but it doesn't help. :( There is a code above.

Comment: 'Reverse duped' to a new, canonical, question/answer

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230942/i-found-no-citation-commands-while-reading-myfile-aux/239438#239438

Comment: For those coming here via a search: The `I found no \citation commands` error is because BibTeX was run on the file, while Biber was requested (recent versions of `biblatex` request Biber by default). One will have to make sure to run Biber on the file and not BibTeX.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sometimes (I am not sure why or when) biber gets stuck. It has something to do with running bibtex instead of biber but I haven't pinpointed it. Anyway, if you get a message like

```
FATAL - Error loading data source package 'Biber::Input::file::bibtex': data source /tmp/par-username/cache-*
```

then, removing the whole directory should solve the problem.

You can find which directory you must remove by running `biber --cache`.

In Linux the command is:

```
 rm -r <directory-name>
```

Note: Do replace `<directory-name>` with the output of the command.

In windows, if the problem exists there too, propably the solution will be something similar, I haven't checked it though.

### Update (after PLK's comment)

For more info look at the biber manual (sec. 3.1).

Comment: This is usually due to the way Biber is 'packed' for portability. On first run, it has to extract various bits of code, and if this goes wrong or gets interrupted then you get errors like the one seen.

Comment: See section 3.1 of the biber manual - it explains this and gives the common locations on various OSes of the par archive folder you can delete to fix it.

Comment: @PLK I really can't find the folder for my Windows machine in the manual. Is there a certain folder or file name to be deleted? If so, please reply the name, then I can let Windows search for the file.

Comment: Run `biber --cache` and it will tell you the location.

Comment: In case it's helpful for someone: even after correctly configuring VSCode + LaTeX-Workshop with biber as biblatex backend, I still got some errors like "I found no \citation commands BibTeX".
What was still using bibtex backend and failing was the LaTeX-Workshop intellisense tool. So either set in VSCode general settings or in a .vscode/settings.json file the following option:
     "latex-workshop.intellisense.citation.backend": "biblatex"

Answer (score 11):

Well if you tell biblatex that you intend to use the backend biber (backend=biber) then you should do it and not call bibtex. With backend=biber biblatex puts the informations in a `bcf` file and not in the `aux` so it is not a surprise that bibtex can't find them.

Comment: Thank you Could you please tell me more detailed? I'm not very common with this theme. So what should I do?

Comment: Use biber instead of bibtex.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I've tried. It writes "FATAL - Error loading data source package 'Biber::Input::file::bibtex': data source /tmp/par-filokalos/cache-6a1f654c9b57c7ffeb35998422a4089cb0e12294/inc/lib/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.dcf not found in ."

Comment: I don't have texlive so I can't help you in debugging its biber version.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for help. At least now I know where is the problem.

Comment: @filokalos. Give from the command line `rm -r /tmp/par-filokalos` and it should work ok. You don't need root privileges for this operation.

Comment: @pmav99 It HELPED!!! :))) Kale mou file, THANK YOU! :))) Thanks for everybody, lads!

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you. The solution for FATAL Error is found by pmav99. :)

Comment: Actually you could fix the problem by `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` ... It seems you use the bibtex (by default).

Comment: If you are using TexStudio just run `Tools -> Commands -> Biber`