# "I found no \citation commands while reading myFile.aux"

Tags: bibtex, errors, citing, auxiliary-files

I'm trying to compile *myFile.tex*, a program which draws on bibtex and biber

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myRefs.bib}
...
\begin{document}
...By the Seuss theorem\textcite{firstRef}
...
\section{References}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Upon compiling, this gave me the following errors

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file myFile.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file myFile.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file myFile.aux
```

I don't understand why this is happening, or what I have to do with *myFile.aux*. Can anyone explain this and how to get around it?

Comment: Hi! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You've asked for the Biber back-end and then are running BibTeX!

Comment: Joseph, is that a problem? I'm sorry my newness is showing here.

Comment: Yes, if you choose biber, you have to run biber.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should run biber to compile your bib file as you have used `biber` as the backend.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Here are the commands to compile your `myFile.tex` and your `.bib` files:

```
pdflatex myFile
biber myFile
pdflatex myFile
```

Comment: With recent versions of `biblatex`, `backend=biber` is the standard, so even Biber is not specified explicitly, one still has to run Biber. For help on running Biber with editors see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem with TeXstudio, and `backend=biber` does not work for me. If you're using TeXstudio too, you have two options:

1. change the default bibliography tool in TeXstudio settings *(Options > Configure TeXstudio > Build > Default Bibliography Tool)*
2. add this line at the beginning of the document

   % !BIB TS-program = biber

Comment: A possible third option (if things get rough) is to give up  Give up biber backend and specify bibtex backend: `backend=bibtex`

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus "Giving up is not an option."

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus It worked. You should put it to answers

Comment: @user3050590 Thanks for motivating; I put it to answers. It was just a thought line, and I am happy it helped someone. Be blessed!

Answer (score 3):

### Quick fix:

Fall back on **`bibtex`** backend. Modify the option of the *biblatex package*.

```
backend=bibtex
```

In your example it would look like that:

`\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`