# BibLaTeX error just inserting package and bibresource

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

It is the first time I try to use BiBlaTeX for  my bibliography because I need to divide it per chapter. So far I have been using BiBteX.

The problem is that I get an error message just by inserting the simple

`\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}`

`\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}`

The error I get is

`Package biblatex error: File 'File.bbl' not created \begin{document}`

It is not a great start!

Any idea as far as what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I assume the error was "not created _by biblatex_" even though you showed a different text.  Just delete the bbl file

Comment: If you switch bibliography setups (or other very 'big' things in your document) it can be useful to delete all temporary files in order to compile from a clean slate. This avoids confusing LaTeX, the packages you load and any other tools involved. Be careful not to delete (source) files that are not regenerated. It is safe (and advisable) to delete `.log`, `.blg`, `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, `.lot`, `.lof` files.

Comment: As David says, the full message in the `.log` file should be `! Package biblatex Error: File 'File.bbl' not created by biblatex.` If your editor only shows the truncated error message, keep that in mind for future reference or find a different editor that shows complete messages (or try to find the setting in your editor that lets you see the full message, if there is such a thing).

Comment: deleted the bbl and aux files. The process now terminated but still I receive error messages: `I found no \citation commands---while reading file file.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file file.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file file.aux` Also I get these kind of messages: `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: LGlaparocele.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: ./capitoli/introduzione.aux` (after I inserted a `\cite command in one chapter

Comment: I got the asnwer here: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230942/i-found-no-citation-commands-while-reading-myfile-aux)

Comment: Yes, absolutely, you need to run Biber and not BibTeX. On the command line you just say `biber <filename of tex file without extension>` instead of `bibtex <filename>.aux` or `bibtex <filename>`. If you are using an editor, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.