# found no \citation commands

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I do get this error all the time as part of the Error:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 22.1) The top-level auxiliary
> file: thesis.aux The style file: plain.bst I found no \citation
> commands---while reading file thesis.aux I found no \bibdata
> command---while reading file thesis.aux (There were 2 error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)

I have looked through many entries on here already, but none of the suggested solutions worked. Here is my code [I excluded `\title \fancyheader` and other small changes from the post below]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathtools,gensymb,upgreek}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{complete.bib}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{theory}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I am using TeXmaker and checked that the settings are on biber. I am creating the `.bib` file via JabRef and it is properly filled. However, the `.bbl` file remains empty. I have plenty of citations in the `\include{theory}` section and used `\nocite{*}` just to be sure I am definitely citing something. That shouldn't cause any of these issues, should it? I also noticed that in the `.bib` file some %-signs are part of abstracts and in the urls – would that be problematic?

Comment: you are using biblatex with `backend=biber`. So you should use biber and not bibtex. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230942/i-found-no-citation-commands-while-reading-myfile-aux?rq=1

Comment: Hi @Thorek and welcome to TeX.SE. Do you know how to compile `biber` (necessary for `biblatex`) in your editor? TeXmaker: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/biblatex-biber-texmaker-miktex

Comment: Yes, I follwed that scheme, but that did not resolve the problem.  PDFLATEX -> BIBTEX -> PDFLATEX

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am using the "bibtex %" in the bib(la)tex command

Comment: biber is not bibtex!

Comment: LaTeX Error: File `biber.sty' not found. So I will look for that now :)

Comment: The error message quoted in the beginning shows that BibTeX is run on your document, but the document code shows that you need to use Biber instead. Biber is not a package that you load/use with `\usepackage`. Biber is a helper program (just like BibTeX) that you need to run on your document. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains brilliantly what Biber and BibTeX do. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can set up your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to run Biber on your document?