# How can I print the equivalent of \textcite{} in the bibliography for a cross-referenced entry using Biblatex/Biber?

Tags: biblatex, biber

When an entry in my bibliography includes the `crossref` field, I would like it to print that information as if it were a regular citation in the text, provided the cross-referenced entry is included in the bibliography. Otherwise, it should print the inherited information as it does by default.

I've tried to cobble something together - just for the `@incollection` entry type for now - based on answers to similar questions (referenced in annotations in the code below).

First, based on [Denis's schematic answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/) I tried this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @incollection{incoll1,
    crossref    =   {coll1},
    author      =   {Ard, Liz},
    title       =   {Befriending Reptiles},
    pages       =   {1--45}}
  @incollection{incoll2,
    crossref    =   {coll1},
    author      =   {Keyes, Don},
    title       =   {Asses I've Known},
    pages       =   {342--346}}
  @incollection{incoll3,
    crossref    =   {coll2},
    author      =   {Other, A. N.},
    title       =   {Flamingos of the Arctic},
    pages       =   {3--4}}
  @collection{coll1,
    editor      =   {Anvil, A. N. and Pond, Lily},
    title       =   {Known Beings},
    publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
    address     =   {Mountain View},
    year        =   1987}
  @collection{coll2,
    editor      =   {Ville, Bourne and Tree, Rown},
    title       =   {Less Known Beings},
    publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
    address     =   {Mountain Pass},
    year        =   1989}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authoryear,mergedate=basic,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false,dashed=true,doi=false,sortcites=true,backend=biber,mincrossrefs=2]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{% adapted from standard.bbx based on answer by Denis at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}%
    {\printfield{editor+others}%
      \addspace\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{edition}%
    \newunit
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {\printfield{volume}%
      \printfield{part}}
      {}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
      {\printfield{isbn}}
      {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\begin{document}
  \textcite{incoll1}
  \textcite{incoll2}
  \textcite{incoll3}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This does not, unfortunately, get me the full label for the cross-referenced entry: I just get the year in parentheses rather than the author-year label, and I've also managed to temporarily lose the page range etc.:

[image: only dates]

Based on [Paul Stanley's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54844/) addressing a similar question for alpha-style labels (rather than author-year), I also tried this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @incollection{incoll1,
    crossref    =   {coll1},
    author      =   {Ard, Liz},
    title       =   {Befriending Reptiles},
    pages       =   {1--45}}
  @incollection{incoll2,
    crossref    =   {coll1},
    author      =   {Keyes, Don},
    title       =   {Asses I've Known},
    pages       =   {342--346}}
  @incollection{incoll3,
    crossref    =   {coll2},
    author      =   {Other, A. N.},
    title       =   {Flamingos of the Arctic},
    pages       =   {3--4}}
  @collection{coll1,
    editor      =   {Anvil, A. N. and Pond, Lily},
    title       =   {Known Beings},
    publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
    address     =   {Mountain View},
    year        =   1987}
  @collection{coll2,
    editor      =   {Ville, Bourne and Tree, Rown},
    title       =   {Less Known Beings},
    publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
    address     =   {Mountain Pass},
    year        =   1989}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authoryear,mergedate=basic,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false,dashed=true,doi=false,sortcites=true,backend=biber,mincrossrefs=2]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{% adapted from standard.bbx based on answer by Denis at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}%
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:label}}%
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:collection}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% modified from Paul Stanley's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54844/39222
\newbibmacro{crossref:collection}{%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{edition}%
    \newunit
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {\printfield{volume}%
      \printfield{part}}
      {}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
      {\printfield{isbn}}
      {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}}
\newbibmacro{crossref:label}{%
  \entrydata{\strfield{crossref}}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}\usebibmacro{textcite}\ifbool{cbx:parens}{\bibcloseparen}{}}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
}
\begin{document}
  \textcite{incoll1}
  \textcite{incoll2}
  \textcite{incoll3}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Almost certainly I'm not meant to be using the citation macros here. In any case, I get the correct author-year label for one entry but neither author nor year for the other:

[image: non-labelled entry]

How should I be thinking about this? I'm interested in solving the problem, but I'm at least as interested in getting some clue how to think about this kind of problem.

It is still surprising to me that a standard feature of BibTeX is not straightforwardly supported in some way by Biblatex, but I guess this feature somehow got overlooked in the planning process!

Comment: BTW: One of my new pet peeves is people using `citestyle=authoryear-comp, bibstyle=authoryear` when `style=authoryear-comp` would do the exact same thing. The `citestyle`/`bibstyle` allows for a finer control of the exact output, but especially when the two keys are far apart in the options list, things become unclear and sometimes outright confusing.

Comment: Your first try fails meanly because of `\printfield{editor+others}`.

Comment: Related (but for citations) [biblatex : avoid redundant information](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172669/35864).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

This feature is available in the `biblatex-ext` styles with a simple option: `citexref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-comp,
  citexref=true,
  mergedate=basic,
  mincrossrefs=2,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{incoll1,
  crossref    =   {coll1},
  author      =   {Ard, Liz},
  title       =   {Befriending Reptiles},
  pages       =   {1--45},
  doi         =   {12345/6789/1},
}
@incollection{incoll2,
  crossref    =   {coll1},
  author      =   {Keyes, Don},
  title       =   {Asses I've Known},
  pages       =   {342--346},
}
@incollection{incoll3,
  crossref    =   {coll2},
  author      =   {Other, A. N.},
  title       =   {Flamingos of the Arctic},
  pages       =   {3--4},
}
@collection{coll1,
  editor      =   {Anvil, A. N. and Pond, Lily},
  title       =   {Known Beings},
  publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
  address     =   {Mountain View},
  year        =   1987,
  doi         =   {12345/6789/main},
}
@collection{coll2,
  editor      =   {Ville, Bourne and Tree, Rown},
  title       =   {Less Known Beings},
  publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
  address     =   {Mountain Pass},
  year        =   1989,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
  \textcite{incoll1}
  \textcite{incoll2}
  \textcite{incoll3}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Keyes, Don (1987). “Asses I’ve Known”. In: Anvil and Pond 1987, pp. 342–346.]

The implementation of that feature uses an internal `\cite...` command (as explained in the second part of the answer below).

---

### Old answer

Those short "in" references are "hard" to implement because they often require a major overhaul of the entire driver. As such a solution will require lots of lines of code, many of them copied directly from `standard.bbx` with just a few additions.
There are actually some custom styles that implement something similar, `biblatex-chicago` and `biblatex-philosophy`. These styles have already written their own versions of the drivers, so it was only a bit extra work to add the needed macros.

We can make use of `\entrydata` like your second example, which would have worked were it not for using the style `authoryear-comp` (it works fine with `authoryear`), where `textcite` has to do some complicated stuff.

So we define a simpler cite-bibmacro (based on `authoryear.cbx`s `cite`)

```
\newbibmacro*{simplecite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
}
```

and use that

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{% adapted from standard.bbx based on answer by Denis at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  [...]
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}%
    {\entrydata{\thefield{crossref}}{%
       \usebibmacro{simplecite}}
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}%
    {[... code for full item here ...]}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

in an `\entrydata` wrapper, inside the curly braces all fields will be filled with the information of the parent entry. Which is crucial if you were to apply an author-title style, there the `title` of the `@incollection` will not coincide with that of the `@collection`.
It can also help deal with some weird corner cases in other styles.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @incollection{incoll1,
    crossref    =   {coll1},
    author      =   {Ard, Liz},
    title       =   {Befriending Reptiles},
    pages       =   {1--45}}
  @incollection{incoll2,
    crossref    =   {coll1},
    author      =   {Keyes, Don},
    title       =   {Asses I've Known},
    pages       =   {342--346}}
  @incollection{incoll3,
    crossref    =   {coll2},
    author      =   {Other, A. N.},
    title       =   {Flamingos of the Arctic},
    pages       =   {3--4}}
  @collection{coll1,
    editor      =   {Anvil, A. N. and Pond, Lily},
    title       =   {Known Beings},
    publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
    address     =   {Mountain View},
    year        =   1987}
  @collection{coll2,
    editor      =   {Ville, Bourne and Tree, Rown},
    title       =   {Less Known Beings},
    publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
    address     =   {Mountain Pass},
    year        =   1989}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, mergedate=basic, isbn=false, url=false, eprint=false, dashed=true, doi=false, sortcites=true, backend=biber, mincrossrefs=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\newbibmacro*{simplecite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{% adapted from standard.bbx based on answer by Denis at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}%
    {\entrydata{\thefield{crossref}}{%
       \usebibmacro{simplecite}}
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}%
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{edition}%
     \newunit
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {\printfield{volume}%
       \printfield{part}}
       {}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{note}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
       {\printfield{isbn}}
       {}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
  \textcite{incoll1}
  \textcite{incoll2}
  \textcite{incoll3}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

The approach taken in `biblatex-chicago` is to define a special citation macro called `\bibxrefcite` and then just cite the `crossref`'d item as in `\bibxrefcite{\thefield{crossref}}`, special care has to be taken here to make sure no cite tracker features interfere with the output (we don't want an "ibid." here, or a page backref to this "citation"). So using standard `\cite` is a bad idea, a custom command such as `\bibcrefcite` is a good solution.

`biblatex-philsophy` uses a very similar approach.

Our cite macro approach could look like

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citecrossref}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\usebibmacro{simplecite}}
  {}
  {}
```

Where `simplecite` is defined as above

With driver

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{% adapted from standard.bbx based on answer by Denis at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  [...]
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}%
    {\citecrossref{\thefield{crossref}}
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}%
    {[... code for full item here ...]}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @incollection{incoll1,
    crossref    =   {coll1},
    author      =   {Ard, Liz},
    title       =   {Befriending Reptiles},
    pages       =   {1--45}}
  @incollection{incoll2,
    crossref    =   {coll1},
    author      =   {Keyes, Don},
    title       =   {Asses I've Known},
    pages       =   {342--346}}
  @incollection{incoll3,
    crossref    =   {coll2},
    author      =   {Other, A. N.},
    title       =   {Flamingos of the Arctic},
    pages       =   {3--4}}
  @collection{coll1,
    editor      =   {Anvil, A. N. and Pond, Lily},
    title       =   {Known Beings},
    publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
    address     =   {Mountain View},
    year        =   1987}
  @collection{coll2,
    editor      =   {Ville, Bourne and Tree, Rown},
    title       =   {Less Known Beings},
    publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
    address     =   {Mountain Pass},
    year        =   1989}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, mergedate=basic, isbn=false, url=false, eprint=false, dashed=true, doi=false, sortcites=true, backend=biber, mincrossrefs=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\newbibmacro*{simplecite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citecrossref}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\usebibmacro{simplecite}}
  {}
  {}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{% adapted from standard.bbx based on answer by Denis at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}%
    {\citecrossref{\thefield{crossref}}
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}%
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{edition}%
     \newunit
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {\printfield{volume}%
       \printfield{part}}
       {}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{note}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
       {\printfield{isbn}}
       {}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
  \textcite{incoll1}
  \textcite{incoll2}
  \textcite{incoll3}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Both examples above give
[image: The relevant references read: Anvil, A. N. and Lily Pond, eds. (1987). Known Beings. Mountain View: Sheds & Sons.\ Ard, Liz (1987). “Befriending Reptiles”. In: Anvil and Pond 1987.\Keyes, Don (1987). “Asses I’ve Known”. In: Anvil and Pond 1987.\Other, A. N. (1989). “Flamingos of the Arctic”. In: Less Known Beings. Ed. by Bourne Ville and Rown Tree. Mountain Pass: Sheds & Sons, pp. 3–4.]

---

Just to show what is possible using the power of `biblatex` we can also condition showing of information that could pertain to the child or parent (a DOI or URL, say) depending on where they belong

Again we have

```
\newbibmacro*{xref:simplecite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
}
```

But now we also have extra eprint and addendum info

```
\newbibmacro*{xref:doi+eprint+url}{%
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:doi} and not test {\iffieldxref{doi}}}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:eprint} and not test {\iffieldxref{eprint}}}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:url} and not test {\iffieldxref{url}}}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{xref:addendum+pubstate}{%
  \iffieldxref{addendum}
    {}
    {\printfield{addendum}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldxref{addendum}
    {}
    {\printfield{pubstate}}}
```

collected into one handy macro

```
\newbibmacro{xref:condinf}{%
  \usebibmacro{xref:doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{xref:addendum+pubstate}}
```

In the driver

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  [...]
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}%
    {\entrydata{\thefield{crossref}}{%
       \usebibmacro{xref:simplecite}}
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{xref:condinf}}%
    {[... code for full reference ...]}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

This setup can in our MWE distinguish between an inherited DOI and a "eigen"-DOI.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @incollection{incoll1,
    crossref    =   {coll1},
    author      =   {Ard, Liz},
    title       =   {Befriending Reptiles},
    pages       =   {1--45},
    doi         =   {12345/6789/1},
  }
  @incollection{incoll2,
    crossref    =   {coll1},
    author      =   {Keyes, Don},
    title       =   {Asses I've Known},
    pages       =   {342--346},
  }
  @incollection{incoll3,
    crossref    =   {coll2},
    author      =   {Other, A. N.},
    title       =   {Flamingos of the Arctic},
    pages       =   {3--4}}
  @collection{coll1,
    editor      =   {Anvil, A. N. and Pond, Lily},
    title       =   {Known Beings},
    publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
    address     =   {Mountain View},
    year        =   1987,
    doi         =   {12345/6789/main},
  }
  @collection{coll2,
    editor      =   {Ville, Bourne and Tree, Rown},
    title       =   {Less Known Beings},
    publisher   =   {Sheds \& Sons},
    address     =   {Mountain Pass},
    year        =   1989}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, mergedate=basic, backend=biber, mincrossrefs=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\newbibmacro*{xref:simplecite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
}

\newbibmacro*{xref:doi+eprint+url}{%
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:doi} and not test {\iffieldxref{doi}}}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:eprint} and not test {\iffieldxref{eprint}}}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:url} and not test {\iffieldxref{url}}}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{xref:addendum+pubstate}{%
  \iffieldxref{addendum}
    {}
    {\printfield{addendum}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldxref{addendum}
    {}
    {\printfield{pubstate}}}

\newbibmacro{xref:condinf}{%
  \usebibmacro{xref:doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{xref:addendum+pubstate}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{% adapted from standard.bbx based on answer by Denis at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}%
    {\entrydata{\thefield{crossref}}{%
       \usebibmacro{xref:simplecite}}
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{xref:condinf}}%
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{edition}%
     \newunit
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {\printfield{volume}%
       \printfield{part}}
       {}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{note}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
       {\printfield{isbn}}
       {}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
  \textcite{incoll1}
  \textcite{incoll2}
  \textcite{incoll3}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The "Keyes" entry inherits the DOI from "Anvil & Pond", but it is not displayed to avoid redundancies, the distinct DOI of "Ard" is correctly reported.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is superb. I can see, if you like, why it is 'hard' looking at the code. I just wonder why it wasn't considered when designing Biblatex but perhaps it was just an oversight. Is there any reason that I can't have the chapter-page stuff in the `simplecite` macro, as I did in `crossref:label` in my second example? I see you've got it only for the full entry but I think that's why your output loses the page range (and would presumably lose a chapter number). If that's not a good idea, is there a better way of including that information?

Comment: @cfr You can have that as well, the same goes for the `pageref` macro. But you have to add it outside the scope of `\entrydata{\thefield{crossref}}` in the first solution and outside the `\citecrossref` in the second solution because it should use the information of the main entry again and not the `crossref`'d-parent. If you want I can see if I can include the needed code.

Comment: OK. If you can do it without much trouble, that'd be great. If not, I am happy to have a go and tell you when I get stuck!

Comment: @cfr Done! I haven't updated the image yet, but the required code has been changed. Depending on whether `doi+eprint+url` and `addendum+pubstate` normally belong to the `@collection` or the `@incollection`, you might want to move them as well. (I would have to have a look at the inheriting rules to see if that makes sense. One could also do some elaborate checking to make sure there is no doubling there (if the DOI coincides with the parent DOI, drop it, if not print it), maybe if I have time I will investigate that direction.)

Comment: @cfr To show how awesome `biblatex` is I have added some code to deal with inherited DOIs. If the child DOI is different, it is printed; if it coincides with the parental DOI it is suppressed, to avoid redundant information.

Comment: That's fantastic! I tried the non-DOI solution in my real document, and altered the definition of `simplecite` to `\newbibmacro*{simplecite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace\bibopenparen}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}\bibcloseparen}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
}`. I'm not sure that is the correct way to do it, though. (I wanted to get the parentheses back around the year.)

Comment: I would have preferred `\newbibmacro*{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}}` (just a copy of `cite:labelyear+extrayear`, but with `\printtext[parens]` thrown in) and then use `cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear` in `simplecite`. But that is just because I cannot stand manual `\bibopenparen`s; my solution is also a bit safer if you have entries lacking a `labelyear`.

Comment: @cfr Forgot to ping you in the last comment, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. I don't have a good grasp of how Biblatex works overall which is why I try things which *obviously* won't work. Actually, I'm always surprised if something I do *does* work ;).

Comment: +1: Amazing work.