# Use alias with booktitle in biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have several different works that are part of a single collection with a very long name, e.g.,

```
@incollection{item1,
title={Some article},
booktitle={Very Long Collection of Obscure Conference Papers in Memory of John Doe and Other Studies on Obscure Topics},
...

@incollection{item2,
title={Some other article},
booktitle={Very Long Collection of Obscure Conference Papers in Memory of John Doe and Other Studies on Obscure Topics},
...
```

I am using Biber and the BibLaTeX package to generate bibliographical references in footnotes (I have to use some obscure European bibliography standard). I would like to define an alias for the booktitle so that the first time I cite something from this collection, the full name is printed, but after that, only the alias, e.g.,

As Foo Bar writes(Footnote: See Bar, Foo, Some article, in "Very Long Collection of Obscure Conference Papers in Memory of John Doe and Other Studies on Obscure Topics" (VLC)), but Baz disagrees with him(Footnote, See Baz, Some other article, in VLC.

Is this possible to do with biber?

Edit: Right now I am using the gost-footnote style, which follows the Russian GOST 7.0.5-2008:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir} 
\usepackage{xunicode,fontspec,xltxtra}
\usepackage[style=gost-footnote,sortlocale=ru,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{/path/to/mybibfile}
```

...

```
Some text\autocite[See][p. 123]{item1}, some other text\autocite[See][p. 123]{item2}.
```

Comment: I think that should be possible (it might involve quite some work), but in order to be of any assistance we would need to see what you have so for in form of an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). What needs to be (and what can be) done depends heavily on the citation style and existing modifications you use. Maybe [How can I print the equivalent of \textcite{} in the bibliography for a cross-referenced entry using Biblatex/Biber?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267297/35864), [avoid redundant information](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172669/35864) can give you some ideas.

Comment: Any news here? Would it be possible to provide those additional pieces of  information?

Comment: Can you give any more information about the style you use? I think in its current state your question requires too much guesswork so that it cannot be properly answered. I will probably vote to close as "unclear what you are asking" soon if the question remains in its current state.

Comment: That edit gives some of the badly needed information, but the question is still a bit muddy. It would help greatly to provide a full MWE that we can just copy, past and run.