# How to print only editor and title of parent entry in a child entry in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

In my bibliography, I want [biblatex](/questions/tagged/biblatex) to print only the editor's name and the title of the parent work in the child entry if the parent has at least two children, while what I now get is the full parent entry within each single child entry. The parent entry should then be printed in full under the editor's name. So instead of

```
Test Author. “Testing the second Title”. In: My Proceedings. Ed. by Senor Editor and Senora Editora. Any Publisher, 2013, pp. 10–20.

Test Author. “Testing the Title”. In: My Proceedings. Ed. by Senor Editor and Senora Editora. Any Publisher, 2013, pp. 1–10.

Senor Editor and Senora Editora, eds. My Proceedings. Any Publisher, 2013.
```

what I would like to get is:

```
Test Author: “Testing the second Title”. In: Senor Editor and Senora Editora, eds., *My Proceedings*, pp. 10–20.

[Test Author. “Testing the Title”. In: Senor Editor and Senora Editora, eds., *My Proceedings*, pp. 1–10.

Senor Editor and Senora Editora, eds. *My Proceedings*. Any Publisher, 2013.
```

I am aware that a similar question has been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54799/for-child-entries-with-crossrefs-how-can-i-instruct-biblatex-to-output-only-a-r/54844#54844), but I just can't figure out how I can manipulate the code suggested there so that it prints editor and title. I managed to replace the alphabetic label by the title of the collection (or proceedings or book) by using

```
\printfield{labeltitle}
```

instead of

```
\printfield{labelalpha}
```

but neither

```
\printfield{labelname}
```

nor

```
\printlist{labelname}
```

seems to work to get the editor's name. Any idea what's going wrong here? I add a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
@incollection{inproc1,
    Author = {Test Author},
    Crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {1--10},
    Title = {Testing the Title}}

@incollection{inproc2,
    Author = {Test Author},
    Crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the second Title}}

@collection{proc,
    Editor = {Senor Editor and Senora Editora},
    Publisher = {Any Publisher},
    Title = {My Proceedings},
    Year = {2013}}

@inproceedings{inproc3,
    Author  = {Nother Author},
    Publisher = {Nother Publisher},
    Title   = {In Some Other Proceedings},
    Maintitle = {Main Title of Other Proceedings},
    Year     = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:full}}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:label}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:extrainfo}}
    {}
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:full}{%
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:label}{%
  \entrydata{\strfield{crossref}}
     {\printtext{
        {\printfield{labeltitle}\printfield{extratitle}}}}}

\addbibresource{my.bib}

\begin{document}

Test \cite{inproc1} and \cite{inproc2} and \cite{inproc3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And, one more little thing (too connected and minor a point for an extra question), how can I make the title of the collection appear in italics in the child entry?

Thanks for your help - as it is my first post on TeX Stack Exchange, please don't hesitate to correct me in case I didn't make myself clear, or violated any convention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print the names you need `\printnames{labelname}`.

If you want `labelname` to print full names, then you need `\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}`.

To get (ed./eds.) after `labelname`, add `\setunit*{\addspace}\printtext[parens]{editorstrg}`.

To get (ed./eds.) after the main editor in entry `proc`, you need to patch the `bbx:editor` macro using `xpatch`, like this:

```
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\usebibmacro{#1}}
  {\setunit{\addspace}\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{#1}}}
  {}{}
```

To get the the `labeltitle` in italics you can use `\printfield[title]{labeltitle}` since the default format for title is italics.

So your `crossref:label` macro becomes:

```
\newbibmacro{crossref:label}{%
  \entrydata{\strfield{crossref}}
     {\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}%
      \printnames{labelname}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}}
```

**Note:** This is very specific to your question. More customisation is needed to handle cases when labelname does not refer to an editor (e.g., translator).

Here's the full MWE and output:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
@incollection{inproc1,
    Author = {Test Author},
    Crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {1--10},
    Title = {Testing the Title}}

@incollection{inproc2,
    Author = {Test Author},
    Crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the second Title}}

@collection{proc,
    Editor = {Senor Editor and Senora Editora},
    Publisher = {Any Publisher},
    Title = {My Proceedings},
    Year = {2013}}

@inproceedings{inproc3,
    Author  = {Nother Author},
    Publisher = {Nother Publisher},
    Title   = {In Some Other Proceedings},
    Maintitle = {Main Title of Other Proceedings},
    Year     = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}

\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\usebibmacro{#1}}
  {\setunit{\addspace}\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{#1}}}
  {}{}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:full}}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:label}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:extrainfo}}
    {}
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:full}{%
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:label}{%
  \entrydata{\strfield{crossref}}
     {\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}%
      \printnames{labelname}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:extrainfo}{%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}}

\addbibresource{my.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Test \cite{inproc1} and \cite{inproc2} and \cite{inproc3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try reducing the citations line to `Test \cite{inproc1} %and \cite{inproc2} and \cite{inproc3}`. I get a compilation error with your code.

Comment: My code isn't quite right either, although it does not give an error. (It just gives what I consider sub-optimal output.) The default is to put the title in italics, so there shouldn't be a need to change this, by the way.

Comment: @cfr, good point. But this is because the original MWE contains this macro and never defines it. Presumably the OP defines this macro elsewhere in his code. The output looks OK. I just don't know what is meant to be printed by that macro.

Comment: You can get the definition from the answer linked in the question. The OP hasn't copied all of the required code.

Comment: @David Purton: Thanks for your solution, which worked perfect with me (`\printnames{labelname}` was what I was looking for). One additional question: Do you know a way to include "eds." (or even better, "(eds.)") after the names of the editors in the child entries, as indicated in my first example? Thank you so much!

Comment: @cfr: Thanks for your solution, too - as David's simpler one worked fine with me, I went for that, but yours works as well.

Comment: Do you want full names or just family names?

Comment: @faxminell I think you accepted my solution in error. If so, please change the tick to accept David's.

Comment: @faxminell, I'll update my answer with (ed./eds.) and an option to have `labelname` print full names.

Answer (score 1):

This is the feature of BibTeX which I miss the most.

With BibTeX, this just works: it is easy, foolproof and robust.

In Biblatex, additional code is required for each entry type and that code must be adapted for the bibliography and citation style used: it is hard, error-prone, a nightmare to maintain and, hence, extremely fragile.

Biblatex is obviously far more powerful and sophisticated than BibTeX. It is unfortunate that bloated bibliographies are among the few real regressions in comparison with its predecessor.

---

I think, though I'm not certain, that you want something like this:

[image: less bloated bibliography]

The following is an adaption of code I use, which is itself adapted from various answers to various questions on TeX SE and from parts of Biblatex's standard code. These are indicated in comments in the code.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{inproc1,
    Author = {Test Author},
    Crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {1--10},
    Title = {Testing the Title}}

@incollection{inproc2,
    Author = {Test Author},
    Crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the second Title}}

@collection{proc,
    Editor = {Senor Editor and Senora Editora},
    Publisher = {Any Publisher},
    Title = {My Proceedings},
    Year = {2013}}

@inproceedings{inproc3,
    Author  = {Nother Author},
    Publisher = {Nother Publisher},
    Title   = {In Some Other Proceedings},
    Maintitle = {Main Title of Other Proceedings},
    Year     = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex.cfg}
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
% solution adapted from moewe's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267321/, standard.bbx based on answer by Denis at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/, manual
\newif\iffaxminell@biblatex@compcoll
\faxminell@biblatex@compcollfalse
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{comp-coll}[true]{%
  \edef\tempa{#1}%
  \edef\tempb{true}%
  \edef\tempc{false}%
  \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \faxminell@biblatex@compcolltrue
  \else
    \ifx\tempa\tempc
      \faxminell@biblatex@compcollfalse
    \fi
  \fi
}
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \iffaxminell@biblatex@compcoll
    \newbibmacro*{faxminell:incollection:coll}{% addaswyd o standard.bbx 2017-04-16
      \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{edition}%
      \newunit
      \iffieldundef{maintitle}
        {\printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}}
        {}%
      \newunit
      \printfield{volumes}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{series+number}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{note}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
        {\printfield{isbn}}
        {}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    }%
    \newbibmacro*{faxminell:incollection:crossref}{%
      \ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}{%
        \cite{\thefield{crossref}}%
        \newunit\newblock
        \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
      }{%
        \iffieldundef{xref}{%
          \usebibmacro{faxminell:incollection:coll}%
        }{%
          \usebibmacro{faxminell:incollection:xref}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
    \newbibmacro*{faxminell:incollection:xref}{%
      \ifentryinbib{\thefield{xref}}{%
        \cite{\thefield{xref}}%
        \newunit\newblock
        \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
      }{%
        \usebibmacro{faxminell:incollection:coll}%
      }%
    }%
    \DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{% adapted from standard.bbx based on answer by Denis at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/
      \citereset%
      \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
      \usebibmacro{begentry}%
      \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
      \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \newunit
      \printlist{language}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \usebibmacro{in:}%
      \iffieldundef{crossref}{%
        \iffieldundef{xref}{%
          \usebibmacro{faxminell:incollection:coll}%
        }{%
          \usebibmacro{faxminell:incollection:xref}%
        }%
      }{%
        \usebibmacro{faxminell:incollection:crossref}%
      }%
      \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
      \usebibmacro{pageref}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \iftoggle{bbx:related}
        {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
         \usebibmacro{related}}
        {}%
      \usebibmacro{finentry}%
    }%
  \fi
}
% END redefine handling of @incollection etc.
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-icomp,comp-coll]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Test \cite{inproc1} and \cite{inproc2} and \cite{inproc3}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

If you already have a `biblatex.cfg`, you can obviously add the code to your existing customisations. Alternatively, you can include the code in your preamble in the usual way i.e. by sandwiching it between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

If you need this for entry types such as `@inproceedings` etc., then you should be able to modify those in similar fashion. (It wasn't clear to me whether you needed this or not, so I just did the `@incollection` case, which is the only one I've found I needed so far.)

Comment: Add `\RequirePackage{filecontents}` to generate `biblatex.cfg` from the above code. I removed this lest my code overwrite an existing configuration file. Or change the name `filecontents` writes to e.g. `biblatex-new.cfg` and then rename to `biblatex.cfg`.

Answer (score 0):

The styles of the `biblatex-ext` bundle have an option called `citexref` that allows for slightly shorter bibliography entries.

Just replace `style=authortitle-icomp,` with `style=ext-authortitle-icomp,` and add `citexref=true` to the options.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ext-authortitle-icomp, citexref=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{inproc1,
  author   = {Test Author},
  crossref = {proc},
  pages    = {1--10},
  title    = {Testing the Title},
}
@incollection{inproc2,
  author   = {Test Author},
  crossref = {proc},
  pages    = {10--20},
  title    = {Testing the second Title},
}
@collection{proc,
  editor    = {Senor Editor and Senora Editora},
  publisher = {Any Publisher},
  title     = {My Proceedings},
  year      = {2013},
}
@inproceedings{inproc3,
  author    = {Nother Author},
  publisher = {Nother Publisher},
  title     = {In Some Other Proceedings},
  maintitle = {Main Title of Other Proceedings},
  year      = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \autocite{inproc1} and \autocite{inproc2}
and \autocite{inproc3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Author, Test. “Testing the second Title”. In: Editor and Editora, My Proceedings, pp. 10–20.]

This doesn't give the "eds." in the short citations since it just mirrors normal citations. "Eds." can be added by slightly modifying the `cite` bibmacro.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ext-authortitle-icomp, citexref=true]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro{cite:labelname}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{author}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{editor}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
       {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{translator}
         {\setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
          \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
         {}}}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:inxrefcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:labelname}%
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{inproc1,
  author   = {Test Author},
  crossref = {proc},
  pages    = {1--10},
  title    = {Testing the Title},
}
@incollection{inproc2,
  author   = {Test Author},
  crossref = {proc},
  pages    = {10--20},
  title    = {Testing the second Title},
}
@collection{proc,
  editor    = {Senor Editor and Senora Editora},
  publisher = {Any Publisher},
  title     = {My Proceedings},
  year      = {2013},
}
@inproceedings{inproc3,
  author    = {Nother Author},
  publisher = {Nother Publisher},
  title     = {In Some Other Proceedings},
  maintitle = {Main Title of Other Proceedings},
  year      = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \autocite{inproc1} and \autocite{inproc2}
and \autocite{inproc3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Author, Test. “Testing the second Title”. In: Editor and Editora, eds., My Proceedings, pp. 10–20.]