# biblatex: Use the shorttitle of an xref in bibliography

Tags: formatting, biblatex-dw

I would like to show only the shorttitle of an xref in the the bibliography entry referrring to it. Currently it shows the full information:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{bytranslator}{family-given}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    andothers = {et\,al\adddot},
    editor    = {Hg\adddot} ,
    editors   = {Hg\adddot}
}
\urlstyle{same}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @book{b2,
        year = {2014},
        title = {Redefreiheit: Öffentliche Debatten der Bevölkerung im Herbst 1989},
        address = {Leipzig},
        edition = {1. Aufl.},
        publisher = {Leipziger Uni-Vlg},
        isbn = {386583888X},
        editor = {Ahbe, Thomas and Stiehler, Volker and Hofmann, Michael},
        shorttitle = {Redefreiheit}
    }

    @incollection{bauer,
        crossref   = {schwobel},
        author     = {Bauer, Gisa},
        title      = {Transformationen des Religiösen},
        subtitle   = {Die historisch-materialistische Geschichtsschreibung in der DDR als Heilsgeschichte},
        shorttitle = {Transformationen}
    }



    @collection{schwobel,
        title      = {Geschichte und Gott: XV. Europäischer Kongress für Theologie},
        address    = {Leipzig},
        year = {2014},
        number     = {39},
        series     = {VWGTh},
        editor     = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
        shorttitle = {Geschichte},
    }

    @book{bulischop.2006,
        author     = {Bulisch, Jens},
        year       = {2006},
 url = {http://www.kirche-mv.de/fileadmin/ELLM-Downloadtexte/Beste-60JahreMKZ.pdf},
 urldate = {2015-07-28},
        title      = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
        address    = {Göttingen},
        number     = {43},
        publisher  = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
        isbn       = {3525557442},
        series     = {AKZG},
        shorttitle = {Presse},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{bulischop.2006} text.
    text \footcite{bauer} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of the text circled in red I would like to have:

SCHWOBEL, Christoph (Hg.): Geschichte
And additionally I would like to have the referenced entry also in the bibliography.

Comment: Have a look at [How to print only editor and title of parent entry in a child entry in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/377933/35864) as well as the questions linked there.

Comment: Is your question a duplicate and can be closed as such, or do you need modifications to the answers given in the linked questions?