# Switching driver after first citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, programming

I need to tell LaTeX when citing an Incollection related to a Collection via crossref: if this is not the first citation of that collection, then use this driver instead of the usual one.

Is that possible?

MNWE with the code suggested below (I don't know why it doesn't run with the bibliography file inside. Btw, without the filecontents it runs but still doesn't works as expected)

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}

@collection{Col4,
 Editor = {Gino Autieri AND Gaspare Porro},
 Publisher = {Routledge},
 Shorttitle = {The Grand Theater},
 Title = {The Grand Theater of the World. Music, Space, and the Performance of Identity in Early Modern Rome},
 Year = {2019}}

@incollection{Inc4,
 Author = {Mario Rossi AND Giovanni Bianchi},
 Crossref = {Col3},
 Pages = {151-163},
 Title = {Cultural Life at Villa Lante di Bagnaia. Family, gardens and sociability},
 Shorttitle = {Cultural Life}}

@book{rompi,
 Author = {Pippo Kennedy},
 Publisher = {Routledge},
 Title = {Questo è un libro per rompere l'ibidem},
 Year = {2019}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=150mm, inner=5mm, outer=5mm, top=5mm, bottom=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                        
    \setmainlanguage{italian}

\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % necessario per il comando custom per le citazioni di incollection in crossref     
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            useprefix=true,                 
     %    giveninits=true,      nomi per esteso    
            indexing=true,
        maxbibnames=7, 
        maxcitenames=2,
            citepages=omit,                 
            backend=biber,  
            ibidpage=true,
        ]{biblatex} 

% \usepackage{biblatex-opcit-booktitle}     % per avere cit. nelle citazioni di Incollection con crosserf > non funziona in tutti i casi quindi lo commento 

\NewBibliographyString{ibidemloccit,ibidemnoloccit}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
     idem   = {Id\adddot},
    idemsm = {Id\adddot},
    idemsf = {Ead\adddot},
    idemsn = {Id\adddot},
    idempm = {Id\adddot},
    idempf = {Id\adddot},
    idempn = {Id\adddot},
    idempp = {Id\adddot},
  ibidemloccit   = {Ibidem}, % tolto \mkbibemph perché ho già che tutte le latinitates sono enfatiche; Se capiterà di dover avere la "i" minuscola, bisogna mettere minuscolo nel codice e distinguere tra \cite e \Cite
  ibidemnoloccit = {Ivi},
  editor           = {a cura di},
  editors          = {a cura di}
}

\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\printnames{author}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
       {\printnames{author}}}
     {\printnames{author}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\printnames{editor}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{editor}}}
     {\printnames{editor}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:translator}
  {\printnames{translator}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{translator}}}
     {\printnames{translator}}}
  {}{}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \ifloccit
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemloccit}%
         \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemnoloccit}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%                           Ciò che segue è per avere lo shorttitle alla seconda citazione (funge solo in trad2)
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COMANDI PER CITAZIONE DI INCOLLECTION CON CROSSREF %%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
% test to check if we are dealing with an @incollection
% which has a crossref that was cited before
\newcommand*{\ifincollectioncrossrefparentseen}{%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}
    {\iffieldundef{crossref}
       {\@secondoftwo}
       {\ifciteseen{\thefield{crossref}}}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \ifincollectioncrossrefparentseen
      {\usedriver
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
         {special:incollection}}
      {\usedriver
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
         {\thefield{entrytype}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RIDEFINISCO IL DRIVER COLLECTION%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{collection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
   \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}



\addbibresource{archivio.bib}  



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\textbf{Collection first cite} -> everythong long\\
\cite{Col4}\\

Rompitraccia: \cite{rompi}\\

\textbf{Incollection first cite} -> Incollection long and Collection short\\

\cite{Inc4}\\

Something in the middle (for the ibidem): \cite{rompi}\\

\textbf{Incollection second cite} -> Just the short Incollection\\

\cite{Inc4}
```

Comment: Two things: `Inc4` references `Crossref = {Col3},` but there is no entry `Col3` in the example `.bib` file. Only `Col4`. Secondly, you have not actually defined the new driver `special:incollection` anywhere.

Comment: Thirdly, there was an error in my code. It should have been `\ifentryseen` not `\ifciteseen` (as in the explanation). Fixed in my answer. But you definitely need to supply an appropriate definition of `special:incollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the `verbose` styles call the bibliography driver in citations in the macro `cite:full`, which is usually defined roughly like this (the code example here is from `verbose.cbx`)

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

`\usedriver{<precode>}{<entry type>}` executes `<precode>` and then calls the driver for `<entry type>`.

Strictly speaking `<entry type>` need not be an existing entry type, it can be any driver that you define. You could for example defines a special driver for `@incollections` with

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{special:incollection}{%
  ...
}
```

and then call

```
\usedriver
  {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
  {special:incollection}
```

Now you need a way to test whether you want to use the special driver.

If I understand correctly you are thinking about a situation where you have an `@incollection` that `crossref`s its parent `@collection` and you now want to determine if the `@collection` has been seen before.

The test you need here is `\ifentryseen{<entrykey>}{<true>}{<false>}`

```
\ifentryseen{\thefield{crossref}}
  {<parent cited already}
  {<parent not cited already>}
```

Note that this test can only pick up if the parent `@collection` was cited, not if it was seen in another context before (maybe because a different `@incollection` entry already mentioned it). If you wanted to pick up mentions of the parent `@collection` in other contexts, you would need some more advanced tracking that you probably need to code yourself.

You could combine this to something like this

```
\makeatletter
% test to check if we are dealing with an @incollection
% which has a crossref that was cited before
\newcommand*{\ifincollectioncrossrefparentseen}{%
  \ifentrytype{incollection}
    {\iffieldundef{crossref}
       {\@secondoftwo}
       {\ifentryseen{\thefield{crossref}}}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \ifincollectioncrossrefparentseen
      {\usedriver
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
         {special:incollection}}
      {\usedriver
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
         {\thefield{entrytype}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

---

In general I'd expect that you create unnecessary overhead and code duplication when you create two very similar bibliography drivers for the same entry type. I would expect that it is slightly simpler just to code the drivers themselves in a way that they display the result differently depending on the test `\ifincollectioncrossrefparentseen`.

Comment: Can we use your test to change the \cite outcome instead? I need the outcome produced by the workaround that I posted in my second answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539662/biblatex-shorttitle-sorting-problems-with-incollection-and-crossref

Comment: @Teodoro Sure, you can use the test anywhere. I just showed its use here in what I thought came closest to what the question asked: Select a different driver.