# using the shorttitle field in a cross-referenced entry

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `shorttitle` in a bibliographic entry involved in crossreference. I'd like to display the `shorttitle` field when the parent entry is already called.

I have to use `ext-verbose-trad2` style and `memoir` class.

Here an example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[style=ext-verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{2018_Flor_NatchZhizn,
    crossref = {2018_Flor_BogosTrud},
    pages = {515-518},
    title = {Title of the beautiful composition}
}
@book{2018_Flor_BogosTrud,
    author = {Gualtieroni, P.},
    editor = {Brambilla, G.},
    publisher = {Florenziana},
    title = {Lavori teosofici 1902--1909},
    shorttitle = {LT.1902--1909},
    year = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{2018_Flor_BogosTrud}\par
\cite{2018_Flor_NatchZhizn}
    
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]

should give for the second entry

[image]

Note: A similar problem is discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539662/biblatex-shorttitle-sorting-problems-with-incollection-and-crossref), but the example code contains a lot of complications and I cannot understand the answer.