# BibLaTeX: Formatting parent entry when mincrossref-threshold is hit, Part II

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing

If I have two `incollection`s that are `crossref`-ed to the same `collection`, the `collection`-entry will be placed in the bibliography (`mincrossref` by default set at 2).

Would it be possible to shorten the collection-entry in the bibliography as soon as this threshold of `mincrossref` is hit?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@collection{EickerWolf2017,
title = {Ungleichheit in Deutschland – ein »gehyptes Problem«?},
editor = {Eicker-Wolf, Kai and Truger, Achim},
location = {Marburg},
year = {2017},
}

@incollection{Schreiner2017,
author = {Schreiner, Patrick},
title = {Löhne und Verteilung},
crossref = {EickerWolf2017},
pages = {47--78},
}

@incollection{Bosch2017,
author = {Bosch, Gerhard and Kalina, Thorsten},
title = {Die deutsche Mittelschicht aus der Arbeitsmarktperspektive},
crossref = {EickerWolf2017},
pages = {111--142},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{Bosch2017}
\cite{Schreiner2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the `collection`-entry remain the same if it is `crossref`ed once, but look something like the following when referenced twice to save some space:

In: Eicker-Wolf and Truger (2017: 111–142).

(With more than two editors, it would be »editor 1 (et al.)«)

Could somebody point me where to begin? [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118488/biblatex-inherit-only-specific-fields-with-crossref-when-mincrossref-threshold) suggests using `\ifentryinbib` to define a conditional, but doesn’t actually give any instructions in formatting the desired entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles of the [`biblatex-ext` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) (disclaimer: I'm the author) come with an option called `citexref` that does pretty much that.

In this example I chose an author-year base style instead of an author-title style, because you used author-year in your example.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear-ibid, citexref=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{EickerWolf2017,
  title    = {Ungleichheit in Deutschland – ein »gehyptes Problem«?},
  editor   = {Eicker-Wolf, Kai and Truger, Achim},
  location = {Marburg},
  year     = {2017},
}
@incollection{Schreiner2017,
  author   = {Schreiner, Patrick},
  title    = {Löhne und Verteilung},
  crossref = {EickerWolf2017},
  pages    = {47--78},
}
@incollection{Bosch2017,
  author   = {Bosch, Gerhard and Kalina, Thorsten},
  title    = {Die deutsche Mittelschicht aus der Arbeitsmarktperspektive},
  crossref = {EickerWolf2017},
  pages    = {111--142},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Bosch2017,Schreiner2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bosch, Gerhard und Thorsten Kalina (2017). „Die deutsche Mittelschicht aus der Arbeitsmarktperspektive“. In: Eicker-Wolf und Truger 2017, S. 111–142.]

Comment: That helped a lot. Where exactly is the format of the shorter bibliography-form of (in)collection defined in biblatex-ext, for I would like to modify it a little.

Comment: @Kubo https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/4eea5f042fd69edec467c146b16a588608f880b5/ext-standard.bbx#L368, https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/4eea5f042fd69edec467c146b16a588608f880b5/ext-standard.bbx#L146-L170.