# Combine two separate biblatex-fields in biblatex-ext

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-ext

I would like to connect the year and pages of an `incollection`-item so that in the bibliography they are displayed as a unit. In a different case (journal + page-number in an `article`-item) I wrote a new `bibmacro` and replaced the relevant command at the end the bibliography-driver for `article`. However, using a style provided by `biblatex-ext`, I’m not sure how to implement this strategy. In [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569615/biblatex-formatting-parent-entry-when-mincrossref-threshold-is-hit-part-ii) that led me to use [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext), I received this code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear-ibid, citexref=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{EickerWolf2017,
  title    = {Ungleichheit in Deutschland – ein »gehyptes Problem«?},
  editor   = {Eicker-Wolf, Kai and Truger, Achim},
  location = {Marburg},
  year     = {2017},
}
@incollection{Schreiner2017,
  author   = {Schreiner, Patrick},
  title    = {Löhne und Verteilung},
  crossref = {EickerWolf2017},
  pages    = {47--78},
}
@incollection{Bosch2017,
  author   = {Bosch, Gerhard and Kalina, Thorsten},
  title    = {Die deutsche Mittelschicht aus der Arbeitsmarktperspektive},
  crossref = {EickerWolf2017},
  pages    = {111--142},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Bosch2017,Schreiner2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For the short-citation of the parent-entry, after giving the editor’s names I would like to place year and pages in parentheses, separated by a colon and space [2017, p.17–46 → (2017: 17–46)] I would use something along these lines:

```
\newbibmacro*{year+pages}{%
  \space\printtext[parens]{\printfield{year}: \printfield{pages}}%
  \newunit}
```

After browsing through the code of `biblatex-ext` and receiving a few pointers from moewe, I just don’t get where I am supposed to place it, as crossreferencing and various toggles are involved. Could somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the code in `biblatex-ext` so that the page references for `xrefcite` are directly printed in the postnote of the citation command and make the feature use `\textcite`.

First we have to remove the bibmacro that prints the pages from the relevant bibdrivers. Then we modify the `crosscite` bibmacro so that it passes the `pages` field on to the citation command.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear-ibid, citexref=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{libertinus}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand*{\removechapterpages}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
    {}
    {}{}}
\removechapterpages{inbook}
\removechapterpages{incollection}
\removechapterpages{inproceedings}

\renewbibmacro*{crosscite}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:citexref}
    {\iffieldundef{crossref}
       {\iffieldundef{xref}
          {\usebibmacro{#1}%
           \newunit\newblock
           \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
          {\usebibmacro{xrefcitewithpages}{xref}}}
       {\usebibmacro{xrefcitewithpages}{crossref}}}
    {\usebibmacro{#1}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro{xrefcitewithpages}[1]{%
  \printtext{%
    \iffieldundef{pages}
      {\bbx@xrefcite{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\expandafter\bbx@xrefcite\expandafter[\abx@field@pages]{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\renewcommand*{\bbx@xrefcite}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \boolfalse{backtracker}}%
  \textcite}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{EickerWolf2017,
  title    = {Ungleichheit in Deutschland – ein »gehyptes Problem«?},
  editor   = {Eicker-Wolf, Kai and Truger, Achim},
  location = {Marburg},
  year     = {2017},
}
@incollection{Schreiner2017,
  author   = {Schreiner, Patrick},
  title    = {Löhne und Verteilung},
  crossref = {EickerWolf2017},
  pages    = {47--78},
}
@incollection{Bosch2017,
  author   = {Bosch, Gerhard and Kalina, Thorsten},
  title    = {Die deutsche Mittelschicht aus der Arbeitsmarktperspektive},
  crossref = {EickerWolf2017},
  pages    = {111--142},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Bosch2017,Schreiner2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bosch, Gerhard und Thorsten Kalina (2017). ”Die deutsche Mittelschicht aus der Arbeitsmarktperspektive“. In: Eicker-Wolf und Truger (2017: 111–142).]