# Proper value of mincrossrefs for biblatex-sbl

Tags: biblatex-sbl

It is unclear in SBLH2 6.2.20 and 6.2.21 what should happen when multiple volumes in a multivolume work are cited. `mincrossrefs` is defaulted to 2 in `biblatex-sbl`. However, it doesn't appear that the citation of the multivolume work in the individual volumes is shorted at all. So for long multivolume works, the citations of the individual volumes appears cumbersome. I am unsure if it should be that way, or if it should be shortened in a similar way to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569615/biblatex-formatting-parent-entry-when-mincrossref-threshold-is-hit-part-ii).

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{customstyles.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{tdict}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false,citereset=chapter]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib}
@mvbook{DSSC,
   editor = {James H. Charlesworth},
   title  = {The Dead Sea Scrolls},
   volumes = {40},
   subtitle = {Hebrew, Aramaic, and Greek Texts with English Translations},
   publisher = {J. C. B. Mohr (Paul Siebeck)},
   address = {T\"{u}bingen},
}

@book{DSSC:1,
   crossref = {DSSC},
   title = {Rule of the Community and Related Documents},
   editor = {James H. Charlesworth and F. M. Cross and J. Milgrom and E.
      Qimron and L. H. Schiffman and L. T. Stuckenbruck and R. E. Whitaker},
   volume = {1}, 
   date = {1994},
}

@book{DSSC:2,
   crossref = {DSSC},
   title = {Damascus Document, War Scroll, and Related Documents},
   editor = {James H. Charlesworth and J. M. Baumgarten and M. T. Davis and J.
      Duhaime and Y. Ofer and Henry W. Morisada Rietz and J. J. Roberts and D.
         Schwartz},
   volume = {2}, 
   date = {1995},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill
First vol.\footcite[5]{DSSC:1} Second vol.\footcite[10]{DSSC:2}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

As you can see, it is a bit cumbersome in both the footnotes and the bibliography. Information on the number of volumes, location, year, etc, of the multivolume work seems unnecessary if the multivolume work is itself an entry in the bibliography. But SBLHS2 seems ambiguous, unless I am missing something (I couldn't find anything in the blog, either).

Comment: cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570023/short-form-citation-when-citing-a-second-article-from-same-edited-volume