# Link to crossref in bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref, links

Is there any way to make link in the bibliography to cross-references?

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@inproceedings{contribution1,
title={A contribution on D. de Palmas},
author={Squarepants, SpongeBob},
pages={1--8},
crossref={conf1}
}
@proceedings{conf1,
editor={de Palmas, Brian},
title={Proceedings of the 1st Conference on Me},
booktitle={CoM1},
year=2006
}
@inproceedings{contribution2,
title={A second contribution on D. de Palmas},
author={Squarepants, SpongeBob},
pages={48--82},
crossref={conf2}
}
@proceedings{conf2,
editor={de Palmas, Brian},
title={Proceedings of the 2st Conference on Me},
booktitle={CoM2},
year=2007
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\begin{document}
The first contribution \cite{contribution1}
was published in the greatest conference \cite{conf1}.
A second contribution also exists \cite{contribution2}, 
but I won't cite its conference.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which produces the following :

[image: A snapshot of the compiled pdf]

If I remove

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

and replace

```
\printbibliography
```

by

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

in the previous example, I get:
[image: Expected result]

Now if you compare the entry `[2]` / `[Squ06]`, you may notice that the full reference of the conference is not cited again, but linked with plain biblatex.
Is there any way to mimic this behaviour with biblatex?

Comment: See [For child entries with crossrefs, how can I instruct biblatex to output only a reference to the parent entry in the bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54799/35864), [avoid redundant information](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172669/35864) and [How can I print only Author-Date of the parent crossref in the bibliography entry of the child of the crossref?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31499/35864). Some styles also support this out-of-the box: [`bilatex-philsophy`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy), [`bilatex-chicago`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago).

Comment: The trouble is that the modifications to achieve this - though entirely doable - would require an almost complete re-write of substantial parts of `standard.bbx` (namely all `bibliography` drivers with `@in` in it and maybe some more). Often a solution will not be as short and portable as one would like it to be.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for your enlightening comments. Although I did not provided links to them, I already looked at the posts you are mentioning. However, I was not aware of the existence of those styles and will look carefully at them. If you transform your comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I don't think that my comments really offer an answer. But as your question stands like now, I think it is pretty much the same as the very first question I linked to. So if you don't mind, I'd rather close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Deal, I just formulated it with a different tone, but I think it is a duplicate.

Comment: Fine. I just voted to close as a duplicate.