# Biblatex-dw: How to avoid two entries when using @incollection xref?

Tags: biblatex-dw

`xref` with `biblatex-dw` works fine when more than two works, but it is annoying if I use it to refer only one article from a collection/book, because the bibliography shows two entries: one (incomplete) for the article and another for the collection/book.

Pages 13–14 of the [biblatex-dw manual](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-dw/doc/biblatex-dw.pdf) states that the mincrossrefs is set to `1` to avoid incomplete information. In other words, using `xref` implies printing the parent entry, even when there is only one child entry.

So, my question: how can I produce a stand-alone bibliographic entry for a single @incollection?

In the following MWE, the expected result is: one entry for the Hobsbawm article and the rest as is.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{Hobsbawm2011a1,
    author = {Hobsbawm, Eric},
    title = {On the \emph{Communist Manifesto}},
    pages = {101--120},
    xref = {Hobsbawm2011a},
}
@book{Hobsbawm2011a,
    author = {Hobsbawm, Eric},
    title = {How to Change the World. Reflections on Marx and Marxism},
    shorttitle = {How to Change the World},
    publisher = {Yale},
    address = {New Haven/London},
    year = {2011},
}
@collection{Cowling2002,
    booktitle = {Marx's \emph{Eighteenth Brumaire}. (Post)modern Interpretations},
    title = {Marx's \emph{Eighteenth Brumaire}. (Post){\-}modern Interpretations},
    shorttitle = {Marx's \emph{Eighteenth Brumaire}},
    editor = {Cowling, Mark and Martin, James},
    address = {London, Sterling/\textsc{va}},
    publisher = {Pluto},
    year = {2002}
}
@incollection{Jessop2002,
    author = {Bob Jessop},
    title = {The Political Scene and the Politics of Representation: Periodising Class Struggle and the State in the \emph{Eighteenth Brumaire}},
    shorttitle = {The Political Scene and the Politics of Representation},
    pages = {179--194},
    xref = {Cowling2002}
}
@incollection{Martin2002,
    author = {Martin, James},
    title = {Performing Politics: Class, Ideology and Discourse in Marx's  \emph{Eighteenth Brumaire}},
    shorttitle = {Performing Politics},
    pages = {129--142},
    xref = {Cowling2002}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authortitle-dw,
%firstfull=true,
xref=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\cite{Hobsbawm2011a1}

\cite{Martin2002}

\cite{Jessop2002}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE. biblatex-dw with @incollection xref]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xref` field is, by design, such that the child entry will never inherit data from the parent. The alternative is `crossref` on which `xref` is based. (The primary difference being precisely the inheritance one.)

So you could do this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{Hobsbawm2011a1,
    author = {Hobsbawm, Eric},
    title = {On the {\mkbibemph{Communist Manifesto}}},
    pages = {101--120},
    crossref = {Hobsbawm2011a},
}
@book{Hobsbawm2011a,
    author = {Hobsbawm, Eric},
    title = {How to Change the World. Reflections on Marx and Marxism},
    shorttitle = {How to Change the World},
    publisher = {Yale},
    address = {New Haven/London},
    year = {2011},
}
@collection{Cowling2002,
    booktitle = {Marx's \emph{Eighteenth Brumaire}. (Post)modern Interpretations},
    title = {Marx's \emph{Eighteenth Brumaire}. (Post){\-}modern Interpretations},
    shorttitle = {Marx's \emph{Eighteenth Brumaire}},
    editor = {Cowling, Mark and Martin, James},
    address = {London, Sterling/\textsc{va}},
    publisher = {Pluto},
    year = {2002}
}
@incollection{Jessop2002,
    author = {Bob Jessop},
    title = {The Political Scene and the Politics of Representation: Periodising Class Struggle and the State in the \emph{Eighteenth Brumaire}},
    shorttitle = {The Political Scene and the Politics of Representation},
    pages = {179--194},
    xref = {Cowling2002}
}
@incollection{Martin2002,
    author = {Martin, James},
    title = {Performing Politics: Class, Ideology and Discourse in Marx's  \emph{Eighteenth Brumaire}},
    shorttitle = {Performing Politics},
    pages = {129--142},
    xref = {Cowling2002}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authortitle-dw,
mincrossrefs=2,
xref=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\cite{Hobsbawm2011a1}

\cite{Martin2002}

\cite{Jessop2002}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: one or many]

The disadvantage of this is that if you change all of your `xref` to `crossref`, the information about a collection will be repeated for every entry.

This is the one big disadvantage I'm aware of of using `biblatex` rather than traditional BibTeX. Not only could BibTeX do this. It 'just works' with BibTeX in the way you'd intuitively expect.

In contrast, if there is a good `biblatex` solution, I've not yet found it. For some reason, it just seems to have been designed to do what is almost always going to be the Wrong Thing. I have no idea whatsoever why. Worse still, the Wrong Thing is not just the default. It appears the be the only possible setting. (No doubt I am merely blind to the advantages of its approach. But there we go. Blind I am.)

Comment: Should not this be a feature request then? (The fact that it should behave the right way)

Comment: @pluton But it seems to be by design. This is a break with the BibTeX approach. See the comments following [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192957/). [Note that the answer is mine and I do not recommend it!]. None of the hacks for this are in any way satisfactory.... The most authoritative answer (in that it sources GitHub) is maybe [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118850/) but it requires modifying all affected drivers (and that will be style-specific, too).

Comment: It is a pity that biblatex doesn't provide an automatic solution to this issue. The strange thing: using 'firstfull=true' (only xref, no crossref) renders —as expected— all data in the first citation while it prints only the basic data on the second.

Comment: @Ludenticus You could file a feature request asking for an option enabling this behaviour, based on the `\inentryinbib` switch. At least for the standard styles. (I don't know if it would be possible to implement a general solution, but if the standard styles supported it, other styles might follow suit.)